Restart Oracle Cloud Data Integration pipeline from the failed state
We are currently using the Oracle Cloud Data Integration pipeline to run tasks consisting of data loader tasks, data integration flow and Oracle SQL procedures. Whenever we restart the pipeline after failure, it starts from the beginning, not from the failed point or state.
Does the pipeline have any feature that enables it to start from the failed state? If not then what are the alternatives that can be used to resolve this?
Provider: Oracle Cloud Infrastructure
Service: Oracle Data Integration Service
Application: Oracle Data Integration Pipeline.
Thanks.
